# Installing an older version of QT

Tags: qt

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 x64 desktop.  I installed qt using the command sudo apt-get install qt5-default. All went well except I need QT 5.9.5. I see under the build and run tab the following
QT 5.12.8 (qt5)  /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake

I need QT 5.9.5. I have read that all I need to do is download and run qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.9.5.run. I ran that file and it set up a QT5 folder in my home directory but I don't see a qmake to select from in that directory or any of the sub directories.  I see QT creator in that folder. It runs but I still have no way of setting up the correct qmake. In fact the QTcreator in the new home directory still finds version 5.12.8 in my /usr/lib/qt5/bin directory.

I would really like to be able to just install QT that was with version 18.04 of ubuntu. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It looks like you did not uninstall `qt5-default`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After looking at your reply I did decide that the best coarse was to use the version of Qt that came with the distribution.  Once I decided to go down that path it was just a matter of making the changes in the code that were necessary to run under Qt 5. I initially thought that this was not something I wanted to do but it turned out to be not so bad.